# what 'a hatch' really means

Tags: meaning, word-usage

i got sentence says "At a luxury resort where the bungalows are suspemded over the water with a hatch in the floor so you can feed the fish underneath"
What the 'a hatch' words exactly telling you?

Answer (score 1):

What dictionary did you use to look up the word *hatch* in? Here's [**one of the several definitions**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hatch) for the word *hatch* that I found in the Merriam-Webster Dictionary:

> an opening in the deck of a ship or in the floor or roof of a building

So, it's basically a small door in the floor that can be opened and closed that allows you to see the water underneath your house. Here's a picture of a hatch that would in principle look similar to the one they're talking about in that passage of yours (what you see in this picture is actually called a trapdoor, but the idea is more or less the same):

[image]